# How to test facebook login using react-native detox

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox, react-native-fbsdk

How can I test if the login with facebook is working with detox e2e test?

I don't need to pass the full login process (should be greate but we can use mocking for that) but I only want to test if a tap on the login with facebook button will open the facebook login screen (or prompt the user to accept this)

The main reason for that is that due to a package update + iOS13 update, this button was not working anymore, this was a bug in the version of the FBSD we use.

As our tester don't test all app feature for each release, they don't check this button and don't see that it was broken before app release.
We want to detect this kind of failure before our user

Answer (score 0):

Detox cannot interact or assert with web views and system alerts. Mock your code to display some text (instead of actually using the FBSDK), then verify the text is there.